# How to get access to a foreign Vue3 instance to call a function?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

How could I get access to a Vue 3 instance from which I don't know the name of the variable which stores this instance? There I need to call a function from a specific component.

When typing `$0.__vue_app__` in the console (Chrome Developer Tools), I see the data of the instance, but how could I use this in my code inside a JS file?

`console.log($0)` will be undefined of course.

Which way I could go here?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. The only way I see is to dispatch an event in one component and listening for it in another.

Comment: But for that I would need access within the Vue component, right?

Comment: Consider explaining your case. If these are your own apps you have to provide a way for them to interact.

Comment: The Vue3 application it's not an own. We plan to extend a custom Vue project with third party addons. So we have no access to the vue code. We have only the build :-)

Comment: @asored $0 is just currently selected DOM element in devtools. You need to select an element programmatically in your own app at the moment when another app has been initialized

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use a [worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker) in `mounted()` such as:

```
methods: {
    myFunction(){
        console.log('It works!');
    }
},
mounted() {
    window["myWorker"] = new Worker("./myWorker.js");

    window["myWorker"].onmessage = function(event) {
        if (event && event.data === 'run_my_function') {
            this.myFunction();
        }
    }
}
```

In `myWorker.js` уоu can do:

```
this.postMessage('run_my_function');
```

Comment: Why a worker? Could be window events

Comment: @EstusFlask Sure, provide an example as an alternative option. There are several options.

Comment: The Vue3 application it's not an own. We plan to extend a custom Vue project with third party addons. So we have no access to the vue code. We have only the build :-) Therefore this solution will not work I guess..

Comment: @asored In that case I don't believe there's a way to "hack" a Vue app and run functions within it, unless the developers of the Vue app are willing to add such workers and window events to "listen" to your custom events, this would be called an API, if the Vue app doesn't have such an API then there's no reliable way to do it.

Comment: @MaxS. Hmm.. in this case, concretely, we want to add more functionality to an existing page builder for WordPress, which has been created in Vue3. I see other plugins which do the same, for example adding more items in the builder context menus or basicly interacting with the state. Currently there is no official API for the vue level. How the developers do this? Is this really just dispatching click events to simulate the actions and adding new items injecting them via js on page load? What do you think?

Comment: @asored Is this something like Elementor? Give me the name of the plugins and I'll install them and have a look. Adding items to a menu is easy with jQuery, or they maybe adding data to a json object in global window and since Vue is reactive it's updating the menu items accordingly, or maybe hooking to the plugins functions on the backend and sending additional data to the plugin.

Comment: Thanks @MaxS. :) I'm talking about Bricks Builder. If you like to take a look, I could send you login data for a dev site :) Currently I'm hacking with Event Dispatching in combination with MutationObservers to, for example, add elements via a terminal like syntax (> div > heading*5). It works, but the code is dirty and complex. I always search for more clean solutions..what do you think?

Comment: @Vueer I would have to install it locally and test the backend, but a quick look online it looks like they do have an API: https://academy.bricksbuilder.io/topic/basics/

Does that enable уоu to achieve what уоu need?

Comment: Nope, this is only PHP side to create custom elements for example. Inside the builder UI (which is built in vue3, there is currently no way to interact.

Comment: (Therefore I try to go very crazy ways to achieve what I need. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74817824/strange-error-with-asynchronous-code-in-mutation-observer) Hehe :-)

Comment: What you're trying to do is hack a Vue app, not "interact" with it. You think the developers of the Vue framework didn't think of that?

Comment: I would call it "interacting.". Maybe we have misunderstood each other. The goal is to execute exactly the same functions that are executed anyway, just by using shortcuts, for example. Nothing new is added and nothing is changed. That’s the same how Plaster for example is doing it in another way: https://plaster-plugin.com/ (Adding additional features to improve the usability)

Comment: @Vueer It's called vue as in "view" because you're meant to "interact" with the user interface. It's not called interacting what you're trying to do.